# Using Isotop to filter on date

Tags: javascript, jquery-isotope

I have a table sorted and filtered by isotope JS. I want to add a filter by date, to show the results between two dates selected by a datepicker.
Any idea how to do this ?

Thank you

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: I changed my code, and now i'm using DataTables, wich is more conveniant for table filtering and sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use custom filter function -

```
$grid.isotope({ filter: function() {
  var date= $(this).find('.date').text();
  return (date comparison here);
} })
```